# Understanding the full architecture of Infinispan?

Tags: architecture, infinispan

I am starting a project with a client where a central part is high performance caching of a large dataset. I am at the moment looking into various OSS projects and Infinispan looks very interesting. I have however yet to find a good "architecture" level overview of what cache configurations that are possible etc.
Our requirements are basically:

1. Ability to create a local (library) on-heap (Java) L1 cache, an off-heap or possible persisted L2 cache and possibly a distributed L3 cache.
2. The L1 and L2 caches need to be "exclusive" i.e. the entries of the L1 should NOT be present also in the L2 cache as this would cost too much memory.
3. The L1 cache should preferably use one of the latest and most efficient eviction algorithms (in my view TinyFLU is a good candidate for this).

Can anybody provide some guidance on if/how these things can be archived with Infinispan and where I can read up on how to create a multi-tier combined library + distributed setup as described (is the manual only resource or are there other more "architecture" level resources I can also use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Distributed cache may match most of the requirements ([Distributed Cache Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#distributed-caches_clustered-caches))

In a distributed cache, your data is partitioned and stored in different nodes. When reading, if the node is an owner of that key, it reads from local memory (on-heap or off-heap), otherwise, it will do an RPC to the owner of that key. (so, your L3 cache).

About L2 requirement, it can be achieved with persistence storage ([Persistence Storage Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#persistence)) with passivation enabled. Passivation will ensure your data lives in memory or in the disk. Data will only be stored in the disk when the eviction strategy removes it from memory ([Eviction Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#eviction-strategies_configuring-memory-usage)).

The L1 requirement can be partially achieved by enabling L1 cache ([L1 Cache for Distributed Cache Documentation)](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#level-one-caches_clustered-caches). When reading the data from a remote node, it is stored in the local memory. This L1 data never goes to the persistence storage and it is removed when eviction needs to free some space or if the data is updated by the local or remote node.

---

Another alternative is Replicated Caches ([Replicated Cache Documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#replicated-caches_clustered-caches)). A replicated cache keeps a copy of the full dataset in all nodes. With Eviction and Persistence Storage, it ensures your reads will find the data in memory or in the disk, and no RPC is required to fetch the data. The disadvantage is the writes, which have to sync all the nodes.

Comment: Thanks - will look deeper into your links!